# how to trace the state of a transaction after submit?

Tags: transactions

After submitting a transaction I want to verify that transaction. Is there any API or way to check or verify the transaction?

```
const sendMultiSignatureTransaction = async (receiverPublicKey, transferMeta) => {
try {
    const public_key = await getAddress()
    const private_key = await getPrivateKey()
    const { receive_currency, receive_cents } = transferMeta.transfer
    const senderAcc = await server.loadAccount(public_key)
    const rootKeypair = StellarSdk.Keypair.fromSecret(private_key)
    const convertedAmount = convertTransferAmount(receive_currency, parseInt(receive_cents)/100)
    transferMeta.transfer.token_amount = convertedAmount
    transferMeta.transfer.mto_id = public_key

    const transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(senderAcc)
        .addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.payment({
            destination: receiverPublicKey,
            asset: StellarSdk.Asset.native(),
            amount: convertedAmount
        }))
        .build()

    // Sign transaction
    transaction.sign(rootKeypair)

    // Encode: transaction
    const encoded = transaction.toEnvelope().toXDR('base64')

    // Send transaction for second signature
    return await axios.post(`http://zed-api.herokuapp.com/transactions/sign`, {
        transaction: encoded,
        primary_address: public_key,
        transfer_meta: transferMeta,
        receiver_address: receiverPublicKey
    })
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
}
```

}

I couldn't find any solution to validate a transaction after submit

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing what kind of API Zed is hosting. It's not a Horizon server, so it looks like you're in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not show where you submit the transaction to horizon. Submitted transactions that are successful return a transaction hash. 
See this guide for building transactions as an example: https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/get-started/transactions.html#building-a-transaction